# best way to handle oledbconnections

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization, oledb

i learned by searching stack overflow  and other sites that singleton is a bad programming practice.
i'am relying heavily on OleDbConnection to connect to an SqlServer , i have pages that can instantiate like 20+ times a connection . i wanted to replace this by a singleton  to avoid opening connections when there's already a connection opened.

My questions are :
Is Singleton in my case bad ?
What is the best way to achieve multiple connections on an sql server 2008 ?

Comment: I won't get involved in the singleton discussion, but if you use a static variable for the singleton, remember that it will be not only shared with the rest of the page but also with any other page that may be running in the same application pool. That will complicate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you describe has nothing to do with Singleton... singleton itself is neither bad nor good - only when used for the wrong reason it is bad (as everything).

as for your connection issue:

This situation is usually solved/handled via a connection pool...

You could implement that yourself (not recommended)... depending on the ADO.NET provider you use it might already come with a well-implemented and well-tested connection pool (for example the one from Devart - not affiliated, just a happy customer)...

Connection pools provide sort of a cache for DB connections... when you need one you acquire it from the pool, when you are finished you return it to the pool... the pool keeps connections around (for some configurable time period since last use or similar)... since the connections in the pool are already created and open you gain a significant speed advantage...

OTOH you can't really profit from a connection pool if the connections you use use different logins and/or connection settings...

**UPDATE:**

OleDB comes with a built-in connection pooling mechanism - see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502.aspx) for details. According to MSDN it is enabled by default... on closing/disposing the connection it will automatically be returned to the pool... which in turn means for your situation that you might already be using the pooling mechanism (assuming you are using the default settings for OleDB).

Comment: Well i read a lot about connection pooling , but how i know if my system actually is using them, MSDN says i'm already using connection pooling because im using oledb and oledb is using it. "The .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB automatically pools connections using OLE DB session pooling" source MSDN

Comment: @Flob if you didn't change the default settings for OleDB it should be using them... if you want to check you can try to check open sessions on the DB server (for example via SQL Server Management Studio).

Answer (score 1):

Singleton is not the right choice in your case because it is a recommended practise to close the connection as soon as you are done with your database transaction.Even if you need database connection frequently, you should open connection whenever you need and close it as soon as possible.

Other than that Singleton is not a bad programming practise at all. Singleton is a widely used pattern in programming. No pattern is bad programming practise. It is just that you should be using them in a scenario where they fit in and make perfect sense. If you will use a pattern in a inappropriate scenario that would be a bad programming practise.

**Edit**

Just to be clear, in my opinion, rule of thumb should be that you should not keep a connection open for operations in future. If there are some pending transactions, obviously it would be best to use the same connection to execute all the transactions. But again you should not keep the connection open for something that you might need to do in future

Comment: that answer the first question , i was pretty sure that in my case singleton is not an option . You are saying that i must just open connections/close them in every request ?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. There won't be any performance benefits for keeping the connection open or by using the same object for opening connection

Comment: @HarisHasan that is plain wrong... having an open connection ready for reuse is a plus regarding performance...

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, see the updated answer for more clarity

Comment: @HarisHasan thanks for the update... I am not sure you understand how connection pooling works... upon closing the connection it is returned to the pool while (technically speaking) keeping the network connection/session open... with OleDB that is even the default built-in behaviour... if a connection in the pool is not used for some it will eventually be closed... this is esp. usefull when you have a multi-threaded app like in ASP.NET .

Comment: `if a connection in the pool is not used for some time it will eventually be closed` is it true even if I explicitly keep a connection open through my SQLCOnnection object?

Comment: @HarisHasan if you don't return the connection to the pool it won't be closed by the pool since the pool assumes that it is "in use".